# Charging batteries while powering device

Tags: batteries, charging, lithium

This may be somewhat of a common question although there are some specific challenges in this one.

I have a bluetooth speaker which no longer charges its internal Li-ion cell. Using a new cell I can power the speaker's circuits from the cell although the circuit no longer charges the battery when connected to its 5v DC source. I therefore want to add a new charging circuit to fix this. Excuse the rudimentary circuit diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZxOTN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From reading up on many questions here I understand that it is not ideal to charge the battery and run the device from the battery at the same time? Assuming this is correct I need a way to disconnect the battery from the device's load when the external power is running. The charging board I have does not have separate pins/connectors for power out while charging.

My knowledge of circuits and electronics is very limited. How would I go about connecting the new charging board and having it work flawlessly?

Answer (score 2):

This is the chip you are looking for: http://www.ti.com/product/bq24079

If you take a special care for the charging(like using smart charger) you decrase the risk of damaging the battery. This chip, both charges the battery and run the system simultaneously.

not: look up the reference design and try to draw the same layout so it will be painless and smooth design.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the link. Although that chip looks like the perfect solution I think creating a new circuit with an IC and lots of other components goes far beyond my skill level. If at all possible I would prefer to use ready made circuits. The one I had in mind and am able to source is similar to this: http://lygte-info.dk/review/Review%20Charger%20TP4056%20UK.html